# Nested Loops headache PHP

Tags: php, loops

How would you go about answering a question like this? I know I would have to use a loop, but my current answer won't allow me to go over an input of about 5 which is incredibly inefficient. I'm finding nested loops a little daunting.

Given the triangle of consecutive odd numbers:

```
         1
      3     5
   7     9    11
```

...
Calculate the row sums of this triangle from the row index (starting at index 1)

```
rowSumOddNumbers(1); // 1
rowSumOddNumbers(2); // 3 + 5 = 8
```

Disclaimer - this is not a test questions. Just one of the practice ones I'm struggling to get my head around.

Since posting this I have found a working answer (three hours later...)
Working code:

```
function rowSumOddNum($n) {

   $start = ($n *($n - 1)) + 1; 
    $sum = 0;    
    $step = $start +($n*2);

 for($a=$start;$a<$step;$a++){

        if($a % 2 !== 0){            
             $sum = $sum + $a;
        }
    } echo $sum;
}
```

This was the original code I was working with that kept crashing out saying it didn't have enough memory. Very inefficient I believe.

```
function rowSumOddNumbers($n) {

    $len = $n + ($n*1);

    $array = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i+2) {
        if ($i % 2 == 1) {
            $array[] = $i;
        }
    }
    $count = 0;
    $answer = 0;

    for ($row = 1; $row < $n; $row++) {
        $count = $count + $row;
    }

    $length = $count + $n;
    for ($a = $count; $a <$length; $a++) {
        $answer = $answer + $array[$a];
    }
    echo $answer;
}
```

Comment: Does it also have to work with triangles with 4 numbers per row? Or only with 3 per row? And how did you store the numbers?

Comment: This can be calculated arithmetically, without any loops at all.

Comment: Why won't your current answer go above 5? It should work with any number, and shouldn't be too inefficient. Show your code.

Comment: @Martijn: Numbers go up in increments, so the next row is 5 odd numbers long, and the following row is 6 odd numbers long.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @Barmar: I have updated the question to include the code that times out due to size. I have since come up with working code that works more efficiently. Updated with this too.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked the challenge, so here it is.
This should do the job no matter how big the triangle is.

```
<?php
$triangle = array(1,5,11,9,7,3);
$u = 1;
$results = array();
$sumrow =0;
for($i=0; $i<=count($triangle); $i++){
    if($i == count($triangle)){
        $sumrow += $triangle[0]; // for the last row add the first number of array
    }else{
        $sumrow += $triangle[$i];
    }
    if(is_int($u/3)){ // for every third number store results and use the same number again
        $i--;
        $u = 1;
        array_push($results, $sumrow);
        $sumrow = 0;
    }else{
        $u++;
    }
}
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: That's a really interesting way of doing it. I've since posting this I've come up with a similar solution I think. I'm going to update the question.